# Tensorflow NMT example outputs only the same word for inference

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Trying to recreate the Tensorflow NMT example

https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt#bidirectional-rnns

with a baseline of just copying the original sentence instead of translating, but getting this weird bug for my inference part where the only outputs are the same words multiple times.

Using the TF attention wrapper and using Greedy Embedding Helper for inference.

Using TF 1.3 and python 3.6 if that helps

[Screenshot of the bugged prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Baja0.png)

The weird thing is during training, the predictions are normal and the loss decreased to around 0.1

I have already checked the embeddings and they do change from each time step and I suspect that this has something to do with the decoding stage since it's the only part the really changes from training to inference.

```python
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

PAD = 0
EOS = 1

max_gradient_norm = 1
learning_rate = 0.02
num_layers = 1
total_epoch = 2
sentence_length = 19
vocab_size = 26236
input_embedding_size = 128

if mode == "training":
    batch_size = 100
    isReused = None
else:
    batch_size = 1
    isReused = True

with tf.name_scope("encoder"):
    encoder_embeddings = tf.get_variable('encoder_embeddings', [vocab_size, input_embedding_size], tf.float32,
                                         tf.random_uniform_initializer(-1.0, 1.0))
    encoder_hidden_units = 128
    encoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=(batch_size, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='encoder_inputs')
    encoder_lengths = tf.placeholder(shape=batch_size, dtype=tf.int32, name='encoder_lengths')

    encoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(encoder_hidden_units, state_is_tuple=True)
    encoder_inputs_embedded = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(encoder_embeddings, encoder_inputs)
    encoder_outputs, encoder_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(encoder_cell, encoder_inputs_embedded, dtype=tf.float32,
                                                       sequence_length=encoder_lengths, time_major=False)

with tf.variable_scope("decoder", isReused):
    decoder_hidden_units = encoder_hidden_units

    decoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=(batch_size, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='decoder_inputs')
    decoder_targets = tf.placeholder(shape=(batch_size, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='decoder_targets')
    decoder_lengths = tf.placeholder(shape=batch_size, dtype=tf.int32, name="decoder_lengths")

    decoder_embeddings = tf.get_variable('decoder_embeddings', [vocab_size, input_embedding_size], tf.float32,
                                         tf.random_uniform_initializer(-1.0, 1.0))
    decoder_inputs_embedded = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(decoder_embeddings, decoder_inputs)
    decoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(decoder_hidden_units, state_is_tuple=True)
    projection_layer = layers_core.Dense(vocab_size, use_bias=False)  
    attention_mechanism = tf.contrib.seq2seq.LuongAttention(encoder_hidden_units, encoder_outputs,
                                                            memory_sequence_length=encoder_lengths)
    attn_decoder_cell = tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(decoder_cell, attention_mechanism,
                                                            attention_layer_size=encoder_hidden_units)

    if mode == "training":
        helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(decoder_inputs_embedded, decoder_lengths, time_major=False)  
        maximum_iterations = None
    else:
        helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingHelper(decoder_embeddings, tf.fill([batch_size], EOS), EOS)
        maximum_iterations = tf.round(tf.reduce_max(encoder_lengths) * 2)
    # Decoder
    init_state = attn_decoder_cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32).clone(cell_state=encoder_state)
    decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(attn_decoder_cell, helper, init_state, output_layer=projection_layer)
    # Dynamic decoding

    decoder_outputs, decoder_final_state, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder, output_time_major=False,
                                                                                swap_memory=True,
                                                                                maximum_iterations=maximum_iterations)
    decoder_logits = decoder_outputs.rnn_output
    decoder_prediction = decoder_outputs.sample_id
if mode == "training":
    with tf.name_scope("cross_entropy"):
        labels = tf.one_hot(decoder_targets, depth=vocab_size, dtype=tf.float32)
        decoder_crossent = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=decoder_logits)
    with tf.name_scope("loss"):
        target_weights = tf.sequence_mask(decoder_lengths, maxlen=20, dtype=decoder_logits.dtype)
        train_loss = tf.reduce_sum(decoder_crossent * target_weights) / (batch_size * 20)
    tf.summary.scalar('loss', train_loss)

    with tf.name_scope("clip_gradients"):
        params = tf.trainable_variables()
        gradients = tf.gradients(train_loss, params)
        clipped_gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, max_gradient_norm)
    with tf.name_scope("Optimizer"):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
        update_step = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(clipped_gradients, params))  

merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.getcwd() + '/train', sess.graph)
test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.getcwd() + '/test', )
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```